# Induced character for non-injective homomorphisms

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reference-request, characters

Any group homomorphism $\phi\colon H\to G$ gives rise to an induction/restriction adjunction between $G$-representations and $H$-representations:
$$ \hom_G(\phi_! M, N) \cong \hom_H(M, \phi^* N) $$
However, it seems that most textbooks and web pages about representation theory inexplicably consider only the case when $\phi$ is injective, i.e. exhibits $H$ as a subgroup of $G$.  In this case, there are formulas for the character of $\phi_! M$ in terms of the character of $M$:
$$ \chi_{\phi_!(M)}(g) = \frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{k\in G \atop k^{-1} g k \in H} \chi_M(k^{-1} g k) = \sum_{\text{cosets } k H \atop k^{-1} g k \in H} \chi_M(k^{-1} g k) . $$
Can someone give a reference for versions of these formulas when $\phi$ is not injective?

Comment: Isn't it enough to replace $H$ bu $\phi (H)$ to reduce to the injective case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Exercise 7.1 in Serre's *Linear Representations of Finite Groups*](http://books.google.com/books?id=NCfZgr54TJ4C&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57) gives a formula (without proof) in the case where $\phi$ is surjective. It is probably straightforward to compose this formula with your formula for the injective case to get the general formula.

Comment: This should yield the general formula by induction by steps.

Comment: Thanks!  I've put them together into the general formula at http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/induced+character .  I'd still be interested to hear any other references for the general (or just the surjective) case.